# Don't substitute HTML entities with HXT

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

How do you preserve HTML entities using HXT ?
The `withSubstHTMLEntities` SystemConfig doesn't seem to change anything :

`runX $ xshow $ readString [] "<doc><p> &gt; </p></doc>"`

and

`runX $ xshow $ readString [withSubstHTMLEntities no] "<doc><p> &gt; </p></doc>"`

both produce

`["</ source=\"\"<doc><p> &gt; </p></doc>\"\" transfer-URI=\"string:\" transfer-Message=\"OK\" transfer-Status=\"200\"><doc><p> > </p></doc><//>"]`

I have absolutely no clue as to where to look. I pretty much tried all the other option that I can pass to `readDocument` or `readString`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `writeDocumentToString` from `Text.XML.HXT.Arrow.WriteDocument`. The signature is :

```
writeDocumentToString :: ArrowXml a => SysConfigList -> a XmlTree String
```

So, for instance,

```
f :: IO String
f = do
  let arr = readString [] "<doc><p> &lt;tag&gt; </p></doc>" >>> writeDocumentToString []
  results <- runX arr
  return . head $ results
```

`f` will return `IO "<doc><p> &lt;tag> </p></doc>"`. (which is good enough to avoid `<tag>` to be parsed as a tag)